# Uploading Photo to google drive and showing into google sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-drive-api, textformfield, sourceforge-appscript

This is my html form and appscript. Whenever the user uploads using "फारम बुझाउनुहोस्" btn, it need to first upload photo in google drive inside the folder "CS_Display_photo-Initial_Request" which is in root folder
[Google drive Root folder has a folder name "CS_Display_photo-Initial_Request"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Weuki.png)

`

```
<form id="photo_form"> 
    <fieldset> 
        <legend>फोटो विवरण</legend> 
        <label for="user_photo">हालसालै खिचिएको फोटो</label>  
        हालसालै खिचिएको पासफोटो वा आफ्नो फोटो आफै खिचेको खण्डमा उज्यलो प्रकासमा दुइवटा कान आएको  प्रष्ट फोटो अपलोड गर्नुहोला ।  
        <input type="file" name="userPhoto" id="user_photo" accept="image/*"> 
        <div id="form_show_photo"> </div> 
    </fieldset> 
    <input type="hidden" name="sheetName" value="Photo Form"> <!-- Add this line to specify the sheet name --> 
    <button type="submit" id="myButton">फारम बुझाउनुहोस्   </button> 
</form> <div id="message" style="display:none;"></div> 

<script>    
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
        let url = "https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbxdFUvsssd_0bAoKmI0ZrUlaQfkI6E73ypmN8r6j_5vrVWBcJ0u_zVJQyBTJ7E-7R6B_w/exec";
        let form = document.querySelector("form");
        let file = document.querySelector("input[type='file']");
        let img = document.querySelector("#form_show_photo img");
        // Shows Photo when photo is added by user
        $('#user_photo').change(function () {
            // get selected file and create a URL for it
            var file = this.files[0];
            var url = URL.createObjectURL(file);
            // update the HTML of the div with the selected image
            $('#form_show_photo').html('<img src="' + url + '">');
        });

        form.addEventListener("submit", (event) => {
            event.preventDefault();
            let fr = new FileReader();
            fr.addEventListener("loadend", () => {
                let res = fr.result;
                let spt = res.split("base64,")[1];
                let formData = {
                    base64: spt,
                    type: file.files[0].type,
                    name: file.files[0].name,
                };
                fetch(url, {
                    method: "POST",
                    body: JSON.stringify(formData),
                })
                    .then((response) => response.text())
                    .then((data) => console.log(data))
                    .catch((error) => console.error("Request error:", error));
            });

            fr.readAsDataURL(file.files[0]);
        });
    });`
```

and here is the appscript

`

```
function doPost(e) { 
    try { 
         var formData = JSON.parse(e.postData.contents); var folderName = "CS_Display_photo-Initial_Request"; // Specify the folder name 
         var parentFolder = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(folderName).next(); // Get the parent folder by name
         // Upload the file to the parent folder
         var data = Utilities.base64Decode(formData.fileData);
         var blob = Utilities.newBlob(data, formData.mimeType, formData.fileName);
         var file = parentFolder.createFile(blob);
         var fileId = file.getId();

         // Update the spreadsheet with the image URL
         var spreadsheetId = "130wSROY1_mscyXvuftCTbENkpqxVcmEsVKhWRa4WFwo"; // Spreadsheet ID
         var sheetName = formData.sheetName; // Sheet name
         var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheetId).getSheetByName(sheetName);

         // Set the image formula in a specific cell
         var imageUrl = "https://drive.google.com/uc?id=" + fileId;
         var imageFormula = '=IMAGE("' + imageUrl + '", 4, 50, 100)';
         var cell = sheet.getRange("F1"); // Replace with the cell where you want to insert the image
         cell.setFormula(imageFormula);

         return ContentService.createTextOutput("File uploaded successfully.");

       } catch (err) {
         return ContentService.createTextOutput("Error: " + err.message);
       }
     }
```

`

I tried changing the google appscript more than 10 times, but didn't figureout what to do next.
Since I am using this feature in my project, It's been like a month, I didn't get hint on where I got mistake. Can you please help me in this
this is my spreadsheet
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/130wSROY1_mscyXvuftCTbENkpqxVcmEsVKhWRa4WFwo/edit?usp=sharing
this is the folder in google drive where I want to store the picture

using the formula "=IMAGE(sth.png)" in google sheet I want to display it.

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your current issue. Can I ask you about the detail of the current issue of your script? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: whenever user uploads, the image, it need to first store in google drive (site host), and need to display it in google sheet, meaning that I am using google sheet as database, and whenever I open the google spreadsheet, that will need to show the photo in each cell (top to button in a column). so that how many of them (user) has uploaded their images with other info(let's not talk about this info only I need is image part).
Can you please help me in with the code I have provided.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I would like to support you. But, I have to apologize for my poor English skill, again. Unfortunately, from your reply, I cannot still understand your current issue. But I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of a solution. I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor English skill.

Comment: Hi. Would you please clarify a few things. #1)Your spreadsheet contains no data (whether real or sample). Do you save the form response to your spreadsheet? #2) When the image is saved/created to Google Drive, do you retrieve that file ID, and do you save that file ID to your spreadsheet (with the other form response data)? #3) what EXACTLY is your problem?

Comment: #1 => My spreadsheet do no contain any data.
#2 => No
#3 => whenever user uploads, the image, it need to first store in google drive (site host), and need to display it in google sheet (just works as database and admin can see that img in cell), meaning that I am using google sheet as database, and whenever I open the google spreadsheet, that will need to show the photo in each cell . 
If you feel like you didn't got my saying, then please provide me with the clear idea on how can I submit file from html to the spreadsheet through appscript.